# SQLAlchemy get Mapper object from Table object (from Metadata or Session or otherwise)

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I find myself occassionally in a situation where I have a table object (such as is retrieved by `Metadata.tables`) and want to get the Mapper object which defines a mapping from some user-defined class to a Table (and then eventually the mapped Class)

In context, I have:

- A `sqlalchemy.schema.Table` object;
- A `sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData` object;
- A `sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session` object representing the current session.

What I want is the `sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper` object which defines a mapping between a user-defined class and the `Table` object above.  I can't find a way to get this via the docs or from inspecting these objects and their available methods.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

[SQLAlchemy-utils](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) has a function called [`get_mapper`](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orm_helpers.html#get-mapper):

> Return related SQLAlchemy Mapper for given SQLAlchemy object.

That function will accept a number of different types of object, test what it is, and then perform the logic necessary to return the mapper.

If you are purely looking at getting the mapper from a table, this is a function inspired from their [source code](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/orm.html#get_mapper) without any of the type checking/handling that they do in `get_mapper`:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapperlib

def find_table_mapper(tbl):
    mappers = [
        mapper for mapper in mapperlib._mapper_registry
        if tbl in mapper.tables
    ]
    if len(mappers) > 1:
        raise ValueError(
            "Multiple mappers found for table '%s'." % tbl.name
        )
    elif not mappers:
        raise ValueError(
            "Could not get mapper for table '%s'." % tbl.name
        )
    else:
        return mappers[0]
```