# SQLAlchemy bulk_insert_mappings(): Could not get mapper for table 'test'

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mariadb, sqlalchemy-utils

I'm stuck trying to use sqlalchemy's bulk_insert_mappings. I got the the point where I can create a session and connect to the db. I have initialized my engine but I can't seem to get the mapper I need from the table.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker,Session
from sqlalchemy_utils import get_mapper

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@IP:PORT/'.format(USER,PW)) # removed my config here
connection = engine.connect()
m = MetaData(bind=engine,schema='test')
m.reflect()

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
s = Session()
s.bulk_insert_mappings(get_mapper(m.tables['test.test']), pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c']}).to_dict(orient="records"))
s.commit()
s.close()
```

I found a bunch of related questions on SO most recently this one

[SQLAlchemy get Mapper object from Table object (from Metadata or Session or otherwise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529759/sqlalchemy-get-mapper-object-from-table-object-from-metadata-or-session-or-othe/51530872)

but sqlalchemy_utils.get_mapper raises:

> "ValueError: Could not get mapper for table 'test'."

`sqlalchemy.orm.mapperlib._mapper_registry` appears to be empty. Maybe because I didn't bind it to my engine. but not sure how to do that.

PS: test is a very simple one column table of type TEXT

Here is the output of m.tables['test.test']

```py
Table('test', MetaData(bind=Engine(mysql+pymysql://USER:***@IP:PORT/)), Column('a', TEXT(), table=<test>), schema='test')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The job of the SQLAlchemy [`Mapper`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper) is to:

> Define the correlation of class attributes to database table columns.

... and it is fundamental to the SQLAlchemy ORM. With the ORM, Python classes represent tables in a database and there needs to be some mechanism that relates the attributes on a class to columns in a table. If you aren't using the ORM, your tables aren't mapped to Python classes, and therefore there are no mappers in use. This is why you get the error from `get_mapper()`.

In your example:

```py
m = MetaData(bind=engine,schema='test')
m.reflect()
```

[`MetaData`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData) is:

> A collection of `Table` objects and their associated schema constructs.

and [`MetaData.reflect`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.reflect):

> Automatically creates `Table` entries in this `MetaData` for any table available in the database but not yet present in the `MetaData`.

So at this point, you have a collection of `Table` objects and you want to perform a bulk insert on one of them. Don't confuse `Table` objects with ORM mapped classes, they are not the same thing.

The docs on [`bulk_insert_mappings`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html?highlight=bulk_insert_mappings#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_insert_mappings) state:

> Perform a bulk insert of the given list of mapping dictionaries.

and

> The values within the dictionaries as given are typically passed without modification into Core Insert() constructs

You are trying to achieve a bulk insert of your data and we can skip the ORM methods (anything involving the `Session`) and interact with the Core explicitly.

The expression `pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c']}).to_dict(orient="records")` returns a list of `dict`s like: `[{'a': 'a'}, {'a': 'b'}, {'a': 'c'}]`, so I will use that example output from here on for the sake of simplicity.

You have the table in your metadata object which you already retrieve with `m.tables['test.test']`, and that `Table` object can be used to generate its own insert statement:

```py
print(m.tables['test.test'].insert())
# INSERT INTO test.test (a) VALUES (%(a)s)
```

And to execute multiple statements we can pass the list of dictionaries to `Connection.execute()` as I illustrate below.

One of the benefits of the ORM `Session` is that it allows for explicit transaction management, where you call `Session.rollback()` or `Session.commit()` wherever necessary. Connection objects can also explicitly operate within transactions similar to the `Session` using [`Engine.begin()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.begin).

For example, using a context manager:

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(
        m.tables['test.test'].insert(),
        *[{'a': 'a'}, {'a': 'b'}, {'a': 'c'}]
    )
```

This will automatically commit the query if there are no errors within the context, and rollback if there are errors.

The engine logs show this expression issues the following query:

```
INSERT INTO test.test (a) VALUES (%(a)s)
({'a': 'a'}, {'a': 'b'}, {'a': 'c'})
```

The following contrived example shows your original query through using `Session.bulk_insert_mappings()`. I've had to create an ORM model to represent the table and add an `id` field to the table as the ORM doesn't like working without primary keys.

```py
m = MetaData(bind=engine,schema='test')
Base = declarative_base(metadata=m)

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a = Column(Text)


Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
s = Session()
s.bulk_insert_mappings(get_mapper(m.tables['test.test']), pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c']}).to_dict(orient="records"))
s.commit()
s.close()
```

And this is the executed query from the engine logs:

```
INSERT INTO test.test (a) VALUES (%(a)s)
({'a': 'a'}, {'a': 'b'}, {'a': 'c'})
```

Which you will note is exactly the same query as we were able to achieve through using the Core directly.

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I needed and a proper explanation surrounding it =)

Answer (score 1):

I have been googling on the exact same question. However, I have found a workaround to this issue.

```
class Helper():
   pass
new_mapper = sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(Helper, local_table = m.tables['test.test'])
session.bulk_insert_mappings(new_mapper, 
df.to_dict(orient="records"), return_defaults = False)
session.commit()
session.close()
```

According to [the following link](https://www.codementor.io/bruce3557/graceful-data-ingestion-with-sqlalchemy-and-pandas-pft7ddcy6), I thought that df.to_sql is performing really poor in inserting massive dataframes into sql tables. However, it turned out that bulk_insert_mappings is much slower.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

for SQLAlchemy 2.0+, from https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html about half-way down the page, in your Base, define:

```
@classmethod
def insert_many_objs(cls, obj_list: list):
    """bulk insert many objects at once.
    param: obj_list is a list of the objects you want to insert"""
    cls.session.add_all(obj_list)
    cls.session.flush()
    cls.session.commit()
```

then in whatever other method that makes the list, such as:

```
# add two test record to the database
l = [Test(a="Hello"), Test(a="world")]
Test.insert_many_objs(l)
```